# Why does onRequestPermissionsResult give two arrays instead of a Map?

Tags: java, android

The method [ActivityCompat#onRequestPermissionsResult](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActivityCompat.OnRequestPermissionsResultCallback.html#onRequestPermissionsResult(int,%20java.lang.String[],%20int[])) gives two arrays in its callback:

> permissions  |    String: The requested permissions. Never null.
>
> grantResults |    int: The grant results for the corresponding permissions which is either PERMISSION_GRANTED or PERMISSION_DENIED. Never null.

As I understand it, to see if a particular permission was granted and act upon the result of this evaulation, you need to do this:

```
for(int i = 0; i < permissions.length; ++i) {
    if(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS.equals(permissions[i]) && grantResults[i] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        sendSMS();
    }
}
```

Why doesn't this method simply give a `Map<String, Integer>`? The operation would then be:

```
for(Map.Entry<String, Integer> permission : permissions.entrySet()) {
    if(Manifest.permission.SEND_SMS.equals(permission.getKey()) && permission.getValue() == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        sendSMS();
    }
}
```

In my opinion the latter is much clearer and more robust. The reason is hardly performance; any given app would rarely request more than five or six permissions at a time. What is the reasoning here? It seems like such an odd and unintuitive design choice.

Comment: Questions of the form "why did Developer X choose to implement Y this way?" are unsuitable for Stack Overflow. Usually, the only one who can definitively answer the question is Developer X, and Developer X probably will not see your question. Anyone else can only offer an opinion. So, here's my opinion: if I had to guess, it is because `Intent` does not support a `Map` extra. `requestPermissions()` and `onRequestPermissionResult()`, under the covers, use `startActivityForResult()` and `onActivityResult()`, so we are gated by `Intent` extras for communications.